# How to write a formula, $S$, so that the set $P_1, \cdots, P_k$ is not consistent iff $S$ is valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A set of propositional formulas $P_1, \cdots, P_k$ is *consistent* iff there is an environment in which they are
all true.

Write a formula, $S$, so that the set $P_1, \cdots, P_k$ is not consistent iff $S$ is valid.

Sorry for asking this homework question. I really don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S := \lnot (P_1 \land \ldots \land P_k)$.

If $\{ P_1, \ldots, P_k \}$ is inconsistent (i.e. *unsatisfiable*), then  $(P_1 \land \ldots \land P_k)$ is always false, and thus its negation is a *tautology* (i.e. valid).

If $S$ is *valid*, then $(P_1 \land \ldots \land P_k)$ is always false (a contradiction) and thus there is no truth assignment that can simultaneously satisfy all the $P_i$'s, i.e. $\{ P_1, \ldots, P_k \}$ is *unsatisfiable* (i.e. inconsistent).

---

According to your post

> a set $F$ of formulas is *consistent* iff there is a truth-assignment such that all the formulas of $F$ are true.

Thus, *inconsistent* (the negation of consistent) means that there is **no** truth-assignment for which the formulas are all true.

This in turn means that there is **no** truth-assignment that simultaneously satisfies all formulas, and this amounts to saying that the set of formulas is *unsatisfiable*.

Comment: The proof is pretty good and clear. But I don't understand what the '(i.e. unsatisfiable)' means?  $\{P_1, \cdots, P_k\}$ is a set. A set does not poess the property of satisfiability which is the quality of a proposition formula.